Ubuntu 24.04: LiveCDCustomization - Unable to Find a Medium Containing a Live File System
I'm working on a script to abstract the creation of 24.04 Ubuntu remixes, similar to Cubic. The commands I'm using are summarized below, and the resulting ISO is barely bootable in VirtualBox [everything I've produced has not made it past the error "Unable to Find a Medium Containing a Live File System"]. To those who create custom Ubuntu ISOs beyond > 22.04 in the post-isolinux era, any suggestions? These commands should be relatively straightforward (given, I haven't even made an attempt to modify minimal.squashfs yet):
cd ~/Desktop

sudo mkdir /mnt/iso

sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso /mnt/iso

mkdir ~/custom-ubuntu

cp -r /mnt/iso/* ~/custom-ubuntu/

sudo umount /mnt/iso

cd ~/custom-ubuntu

chmod +w -R .

cd ~/custom-ubuntu/casper

mkdir extract

sudo unsquashfs -d extract minimal.squashfs

sudo chroot extract glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/

sudo rm minimal.squashfs

sudo mksquashfs extract minimal.squashfs -comp xz -e boot

sudo rm -rf extract

sudo sed -i "s/^[0-9]* .*/$(sudo du -sx --block-size=1 extract | cut -f1) minimal.squashfs/" filesystem.size

cd ~/Desktop

orig=ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso

mbr=ubuntu-mbr.img

efi=ubuntu-efi.img

dd if="$orig" bs=1 count=446 of="$mbr"

skip=$(fdisk -l "$orig" | fgrep '.iso2 ' | awk '{print $2}')

size=$(fdisk -l "$orig" | fgrep '.iso2 ' | awk '{print $4}')

dd if="$orig" bs=512 skip="$skip" count="$size" of="$efi"

new=~/Desktop/ubuntu-custom.iso

disk_title="Ubuntu Custom"

sudo xorriso -as mkisofs \
  -r -V "$disk_title" -J -joliet-long -l \
  -iso-level 3 \
  -partition_offset 16 \
  --grub2-mbr "$mbr" \
  --mbr-force-bootable \
  -append_partition 2 0xEF "$efi" \
  -appended_part_as_gpt \
  -c /boot.catalog \
  -b /boot/grub/i386-pc/eltorito.img \
    -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table --grub2-boot-info \
  -eltorito-alt-boot \
  -e '--interval:appended_partition_2:all::' \
    -no-emul-boot \
  -o "$new" \
  ~/custom-ubuntu

